# possible syntax to search wildcard to fixed length with tablesorter

Tags: tablesorter

Using tablesorter is it possible to search a column using wildcards to a fixed length?

ie having the following

```
aa
aaa
aaaa
ab
aba
abaa
```

is there syntax such as `=a?`  that would return only

```
aa
ab
```

thx Art

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `?` character in the filter widget, it is actually replacing the `?` with a `\S{1}`. The regular expression used to search the column becomes `/a\S{1}/` which finds `aaaa` because there are two separate matches of `a?` ([RegExr demo](http://regexr.com/3e6iq)).

The filter widget will accept regular expressions. To get the exact match you are wanting, you'll need to use the word boundary anchor (`\b`) and surround the value (`/\ba\S\b/` or `/\ba.\b/`) ([regExr demo](http://regexr.com/3e6i2)).

### [Here is a tablesorter demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/146/)

```
// this example will only target the first column
$('table').trigger('search', [[ "/\ba\S\b/" ]]);
```

Comment: outstanding, thanks & +1 for the examples it makes it a lot easier to follow